# Facebook Top Search Url Changed To Mobile

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a web application at Facebook. Recently, some of our users submitted reports regarding the url changes in the top search bar.

http://apps.facebook.com/xyz?fb_source=search
is converted to 
https://m.facebook.com/apps/xyz?fb_source=search&ref=br_tf

We don't have a mobile application yet but url somehow redirects to m.facebook.com domain.
How can I fix this error?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have more information. Some more details could help.

Comment: "Either this application has not configured its Mobile Web URL or the URL could not be verified as owned by the application. Unable to redirect. "is the message shown when that url is clicked.

Comment: Problem still exists on some users. Top search bar url refers to https://m.facebook.com/apps/... etc. How can I fix this?